# Parsing EDN format in swift usinf MPEdn library

Tags: ios, swift, edn

I am trying to parse EDN format using the [MPEdn library](https://github.com/scramjet/mpedn). I have successfully added the MPEdn library to my project. But the problem is I am unable to parse the edn format in swift. I have parsed the EDN string using the `parseString` method of the `MPEdnParser` class and result is in `Any` type of object. Now I am unable to read the value from the parsed object.
My code is below:

```
let mpEDN = MPEdnParser()
let dict = mpEDN.parseString("{:search-input \"string\"}")
print("\(dict)")
```

Any help is appreciated... :)